# Open Remote Desktop and Connect to Computer

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out if it is possible in VB.net to open the connect to a specific computer using the "new" Remote Desktop App from Microsoft.

To be clear, I know how to do this when using `mstsc` but am not sure how to do it with the Remote Desktop App found in the windows store on Windows 10. I am not sure it is even possible, but when I try googling the issue it just tells me how to do it using `mstsc`. So I figured I would ask here.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the only way to trigger a (an?) UWP app is via a registered protocol handler or command line. Looking at the manifest for the UWP RDP app (on my PC that's here: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.RemoteDesktop_10.1.1098.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml`) it doesn't look like it surfaces either :(